# ¿Cómo obtiene el número de decimales?

Tags: javascript, regex

Encontré este código, lo que hace es buscar la cantidad de decimales de cualquier número (incluyendo notación científica) y mostrarlo.

Entonces, necesito saber:

¿Cómo está funcionando la variable `match`, me complica la expresión regular y el porqué del `(''+num)` y el `return`?

```js
function decimalPlaces(num) {
  var match = (''+num).match(/(?:\.(\d+))?(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?$/);
  if (!match) { return 0; } 
  return Math.max(
       0,
       // Number of digits right of decimal point.
       (match[1] ? match[1].length : 0)
       // Adjust for scientific notation.
       - (match[2] ? +match[2] : 0));
}

console.info(decimalPlaces(12.4922));
console.info(decimalPlaces(25e-100));
```

Comment: Al responder algunas de tus preguntas, voy viendo tu progreso, que está genial. Si te animás a leer en inglés, te recomiendo ampliamente el tutorial de http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html que cubre casi todo sobre regex en un orden bastante didáctico.

Answer (score 2):

Empecemos analizando la expresión regular:

```
/(?:\.(\d+))?(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?$/
```

- `(?:\.(\d+))?` - es un grupo opcional (por el `?` al final), que coincide con:

  - `\.(\d+)` - un punto seguido de cualquier cantidad de dígitos.
    Es opcional, ya que el número podría no tener decimales.
    Además, `(\d+)` es un [grupo capturador](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Usando_par%C3%A9ntesis), es el **primer grupo de paréntesis**, por lo que va a capturar el texto con el que coincida.
- `(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?` - es otro grupo opcional, que va a coincidir con el exponente:

  - `[eE]` - letra `"E"` en mayúscula o minúscula.
  - `([+-]?\d+)` un signo `+` o `-` opcional, seguido de más dígitos.
    Además, éste es el segundo grupo de paréntesis, el **segundo [grupo capturador](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Usando_par%C3%A9ntesis)**.
- `$` - todo esto al final del texto.

De esta forma, se ve que el regex coincide con la parte decimal del número (si es que tiene decimales) y con el exponente de notación científica (si es que tiene).

Ahora bien, en regex, los paréntesis capturan al texto con el que coinciden, y se puede obtener luego esa parte de la coincidencia. Más información en [Usando paréntesis (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Usando_par%C3%A9ntesis).

En JavaScript, al usar [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/match), este método devuelve un array con la coincidencia global en el primer índice del array, y la captura de cada grupo en los sucesivos índices (siempre que no se use el modificador `/g`).

Por ejemplo, con:

```
resultado = texto.match(regex);
```

se obtiene:

- `resultado[0]` con la coincidencia global (de toda la expresión).
- `resultado[1]` con el texto capturado por el primer grupo.
- `resultado[2]` con el texto capturado por el segundo grupo.
- etc.

---

Veamos el código:

```
''+num
```

Es una forma de convertir cualquier cosa en un String. Si `num` es un número, `''+num` será el string generado desde ese número. Sirve convertirlo para luego usar el método [.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/match).

```
var match = (''+num).match(regex);
```

El resultado de este método es asignado a la variable `match`, pero no se debe confundir el método del mismo nombre con esta variable que contendrá el resultado (el array con la coincidencia global y los textos capturados por los grupos).

```
if (!match) { return 0; }
```

Si no coincidió el regex, devuelve `0`. -Aunque esto es redundante porque el regex tiene todo opcional, por lo que *siempre* va a coincidir.

```
match[1] ? match[1].length : 0
```

Si se capturó algo con el primer grupo, es decir que tiene decimales, capturados y devueltos en `match[1]`, obtiene el largo de ese string (la cantidad de decimales). Si no se capturó nada en el primer grupo, devuelve `0`.

```
(match[1] ? match[1].length : 0) - (match[2] ? +match[2] : 0)
```

Y luego le resta el exponente, si es que tiene (o `0` si no tiene). Por ejemplo, con `2.3e-4` se cuenta 1 decimal, y luego se le resta -4 (suma 4), dando el resultado de 5 decimales.

Pero también podría darse el caso de un número como `1e9`, que con el código anterior daría `-9`, y para arreglar ese caso, finalmente se usa:

```
Math.max( 0, decimales)
```

haciendo que si es negativo, devuelva `0`.

Y ese es el resultado que finalmente devuelve.